# P <=> (Q v R), P, -Q⊢R Propositional Logic Question

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic, symbolic-logic

<=> is bi-conditional, "-" is negation, "v" is disjunction.

I can't figure out where to take it from line 4. Negated Q is throwing me for a loop.

P <=> (Q v R), P, -Q ⊢ R

1. P <=> (Q v R)  P
2. P              P
3. -Q             P/R
4. QvR            1,2<=>E (biconditional elimination rule removing P)

Comment: Not sure why you edited it back. All I did was format it.

Comment: The period denotes it in a different contextual basis, but it disappears if it's not there, which is odd.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "different contextual basis" per se but the SE markdown syntax is pretty picky. If you really want to avoid the . in a list, then you can use the preformatted syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Given 3 and 4, the normal move is disjunctive syllogism which enables:

1. A v B
2. ~A
3. Therefore B

This would yield:

5. R  DS 3,4

If you don't have access to disjunctive syllogism, then it's going to be a lot harder to do.

Comment: I do not have access to disjunctive syllogism yet, that's in our next unit.

Comment: do you have access to conditional proofs or reduction ad absurdum?

Comment: We only have access to Conjunction Introduction & Elimination, Conditional Introduction & Elimination, Reiteration, Negation Introduction & Elimination, Disjunction Introduction & Elimination and Biconditional Introduction & Elimination.

Comment: conditional introduction is a synonym for conditional proof (https://faculty.washington.edu/smcohen/120/Chapter8.pdf)

Comment: I take it we're using a wide array of synonym's in this course because things are named slightly different when I research them. But yeah.

Comment: Also, is that Kierkegaard in your profile pic?

Comment: yes -- that's  a really big and annoying feature of logic. And yes. I'm a modern philosophy researcher. Trying to think of how to do this with just the list of what you've got.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you taking the time to assist me with this. Figured this would be beneath someone of your status.

Comment: The internet is an incredible place for wasting time  :). If  you have contradiction introduction and elimination reddit has a way (https://www.reddit.com/r/logic/comments/1sukq6/formal_proof_for_disjunctive_syllogism/ce1mie2/)

Comment: The only issue is that we haven't learned about Contradiction Introduction & Elimination yet.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when there's a disjunction you're going to have to use the disjunction elimination rule. So when you see it you have to think how that rule can get you to the conclusion.

In this case, we would need the following:

```
1. Q v R
2. Q → R
3. R → R
```

Using disjunction elimination, these would get you to `R`. You already have 1, and 3 is trivial. So we need to figure out how to get 2. This can be done in the following tricky way:

```
1. ~Q
2. | Q
3. | | ~R
4. | | ~Q
5. | | Q
6. | | Q & ~Q
7. | ~~R       
8. | R
9. Q → R
```

Now you have all 3 statements needed for the disjunction elimination rule which will get you to `R`.

Comment: Assuming he's allowed to do step 7, but it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [virmaior's answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/38716/29944) using disjunctive syllogism (DS). Here is how Kevin Klement's proof checker would format the proof using disjunctive syllogism:

[image]

Disjunctive syllogism is derived from disjunction elimination (vE). Here is a proof using the disjunction elimination illustrating the derivation for disjunctive syllogism from disjunction elimination given in *forall x: Calgary Remix* (page 137):

[image]

Note how this uses conjunction introduction of "R" with itself on line 9 and then conjunction elimination on line 10 to get "R" again. The rules of this proof checker eliminates the need for those steps.

Here is a third version of the proof:

[image]

The OP has the same first four lines and states: "I can't figure out where to take it from line 4." The above shows three ways to proceed and there may be more depending on the proof checker one uses.

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/